# Magento 2 Custom fee not updating in checkout page(Quote save)

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, frontend

How can I update the quote when I open the checkout page?
Like this $quote->save();

Comment: are you required php code or JS code?

Comment: Im use magento 2.4
PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to add before `$quote->save()`

```
$quote->collectTotals();
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but its not help me, how can I update it globally? for all store

Comment: share the code which you try.

Comment: thanks for answer!!!